# Avoid code pausing/freezing on javascript error in jQuery blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, blockui

Let me try to make some sense...

We're blocking the UI using [jQuery block UI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.blockUI({
    message: '<h4><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i> loading...</h4>'
  })
}).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Sometimes, when the code throws some error:

[image: JSON error on console]

The loading message on the freezed screen doesn't vanishes:

[image: loading message on the freezed screen]

The reason is:

1. When the `ajaxStart()` starts, the `$.blockUI()` gets invoked.
2. And before the `ajaxStart()` could successfully finish executing, it encounters an error.
3. `ajaxStop()` is never reached and the UI is never unblocked (`$.unblockUI`)

So, what I'm looking for is a way to show some custom message when there is some error between `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()`. Instead of code pausing/freezing on javascript error.

Also, when I try [@Raghav's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39205860/2404470), it doesn't un-freezes the screen.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.blockUI({
    message: '<h4><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i> loading...</h4>'
  })
  throw Error;
  debugger;
}).ajaxStop($.unblockUI).ajaxError($.unblockUI);
```

Doesn't it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried handling errors using ajaxError()

See: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

```
$(document).ajaxError(function() {
   $.unblockUI();
   // Display error message here
   alert('Some error message');
}); 
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {$.unblockUI();});
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $.blockUI({
    message: '<h4><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i>loading...</h4>'
  })
});
```

You can also fetch the error message. See the documentation for details.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError ) {

   $.unblockUI();
   console.log(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't un-freezes the screen

Comment: `$.unblockUI` is not a function call, should it not be `$.unblockUI()`

Comment: @Raghav Apologies, the screen is not blocking now. However, I also wish to show some custom error message.

Comment: Have added some examples on error handling. @Soren - thanks for pointing that out.